# Resize effect of iOS launch images (and AIR?)

Tags: ios, air

I have a problem when I use launch images in an Air application. I don't know if this is the expected behaviour, but when the app starts, the launch image is first displayed as expected, however then it gets resized for a second.

I don't care too much about this, although since the iPhone images have to take into account the statusbar, the effect is a bit ugly in this case.

Can this be solved? is it a problem with Air? is it expected behaviour?

Comment: how about having a fullscreen app, that will remove the statusbar.

Comment: Well, the app is not expected to be fullscreen, not my choice. Also, having to take into account the statusbar for the iPhone launch screens is what Apple states, they do not talk about fullscreen or not fullscreen apps.

Comment: is your launch icon the right size? (fullscreen, including status bar area)

Comment: Yes, the launch images are the right size according to the Apple guidelines. Also, as I say, at the start of the app the image is displayed as expected.

Comment: then this seems to be a problem with AIR only.. (i'm more experienced in native iOS app dev.). Do you use the image in AIR too? (e.g. as a splash image so you can create a smooth fade from the launch image)

Answer (score 0):

I noticed a similar problem with AIR 3.2 and a fullscreen, fixed-orientation (landscape) app in iOS - the splash image starts in landscape, then flips to the wrong orientation during loading. I suspect it's a bug but couldn't find a workaround.

Since I don't see any pressing reason to move to 3.2, I'm sticking with AIR 3.1 for the time being, which displays the splash image correctly.

Comment: Haven't tried to compile back with AIR 3.1, but guess I'll try in a day or two. I switched to 3.2 when I saw the iOS compilation time was improved, and definitely, I see it takes less.